# Python calling Powershell commands

Tags: python, powershell

I'm building an API that's calling Powershell to get the data.

Everything works fine except **'*'** when I'm running the command using **subprocess.check_output**

```
powershell_call = json.loads(subprocess.check_output([
    'powershell.exe',
     f'{cmdlet_name} -Identity "{identity}" -Server {server} -Properties * | ConvertTo-Json -Depth {jsonDepth}'
]))
```

Error message:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa2 in position 8110: invalid start byte
```

I tried to change the calling method to this:

```
powershell_call = subprocess.Popen(
    [
        "powershell.exe",
        f'{cmdlet_name} -Identity "{identity}" -Server {server} -Properties * | ConvertTo-Json -Depth {jsonDepth}'
    ],
    shell=True,
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
    encoding = 'utf-8',
    universal_newlines = True
)
```

But it gives the same error message.

Is there any way to pass the asterisk character while calling PowerShell via subprocess?

--- EDIT ---

Turned out it I just needed to change **subprocess.check_output** to **subprocess.getoutput**

Comment: It looks like your script is expecting UTF-8-encoded output from PowerShell. To that end, you must set the console's output code page to `65001`. (And it's likely the command's _output_ that's the problem, not the `*` char. int he command itself).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the reply!
I looked up the information for what you wrote and found that all I needed to do was change subprocess.check_output to subprocess.getoutput.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it, I just needed to change **subprocess.check_output** to **subprocess.getoutput**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).